# ng-animate slide animation misaligned

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I've got something working (animation) but it doesn't look pretty.

When the animation/slide is triggered.  The "leaving" slide pops to the left of the screen and hugs the "entering" slide.

It also overshoots the endpoint during animation then snaps back.  My ng-animate css is as follows:

css :

```
.slide-leave, .slide-enter {
 -webkit-transition: 5s linear all; /* Safari/Chrome */
 -moz-transition: 5s linear all; /* Firefox */
 -o-transition: 5s linear all; /* Opera */
 transition: 5s linear all; /* IE10+ and Future Browsers */

 /* The animation preparation code */
 opacity: 0.5;
}


.slide-enter {
position: relative;
left: -100%;
}

.slide-enter.slide-enter-active {
left: 0;
opacity: 1;
}

.slide-leave {
opacity: 1;
}

.slide-leave.slide-leave-active {
   position: relative;
   opacity: 0;
   left: 100%;
}
```

Here's a semi-working plunkr.  Notice the "leaving" view hugs the "entering" view.  You can get the animation started by pressing the black square in the header.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FG44cpJ65S4Gr6QZpm1X?p=preview

Comment: Where am I supposed to look at in the animation?

Comment: A square should show up in the header (top left).  If you click that the animation/slide will start.